# How do I zergling rush in SC1?

Tags: starcraft-zerg, starcraft

I don't know if I am doing it wrong or if my opponent is countering.  How do I do a 'ling rush properly?

The first thing I build is another worker. IIRC only one egg is available for little, but after one or two workers I start building lings.  Two come out at a time and I make either 6 or 10 and run. By the time I get to their base they have at least one unit who can kill my lings or have enough workers to kill my lings and I don't do much/any damage.

How do I do a 'ling rush properly?

Comment: Early zerg rushes are very easy to counter, so if you're playing ICCUP or the equivilent, don't expect it to work.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

> - 4/9: Drone
> - 5/9: Pool
> - 4/9: Drone
> - 5/9: Drone
> - 6/9: 3x Zerglings

— http://wiki.teamliquid.net/starcraft/5_Pool_%28vs._Protoss%29

Answer (score 2):

Your primary goal with a zergling rush is to slow down or destroy your enemy's economy. The biggest mistake you can make is to forget that.

Did your opponent pull off all his workers and arrange them in a favorable formation to destroy your zerglings? Great! A worker that is in a standoff with your zerglings is mining just as effective as a dead worker.

That said, your zerglings are *faster* than enemy workers — if they've lined up to make a kill zone, then flank them. Pick off workers on the edges, don't just charge straight into the middle to get slaughtered.

Same with enemy defensive units. Isolated zealot pop out of the gateway? Kill it before it can meet up with the probes; rotate the zerglings to prevent deaths. Zealot in the minerals? Pick off the probes on the opposite side. All the probes clustered around the zealot in one corner of the minerals? Pick off the unprotected pylons.

In short, do not throw away zerglings — fight the battles you will *win*. If the opponent offers you a fight you'll lose, pick a different fight.

Answer (score 0):

There are a lot of different builds aka x pools. 
5 pool (described above)
4 / 6 / 7 8 / 9 / 11 pool

Each counting the number of drones. 
The more drones the more you sacrifice speed for macro later on.

Answer (score 0):

Building 6 pool 'ling rush is easy and quick however you must keep in mind that it's just not always going to work. You must always scout, because if they wall off you're just wasting your time.

Comment: 6 pool ling rushes dont allow you to scout, you need every drone available to afford the timing properly. It's an all-in.